# Pseudoinverse of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the matrix $U \in R^{n \times k}$  satisfies $UU^* = I$, how can I find pseudoniverse of $U^*U$ ?

I have tried solving Moore Penrose equations for pseudoinverse, but it didnt help.

Comment: Use Singular Value Decomposition.

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: A simple, direct, explanation : https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/05/05/svd/ about the connection between the two keywords ("pseudo-inverse" and SVD). But for your specific problem, sorry but I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo inverse of $U^*U$ is itself.

Proof. Clearly, when $k\geq 1$, $(U^*U)^k=U^*U$.

On the other hand, $A^+$, the pseudo inverse of $A$, is uniquely defined by the relations

$AA^+A=A,A^+AA^+=A^+,(AA^+)^*=AA^+,(A^+A)^*=A^+A$.

It is easy to see that $U^*U$ satisfies the required relations.